# The limit function of decreasing sequence of subharmonic is also subharmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, potential-theory

Let $u(z)$ be a continuous function on a domain $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ to $[−\infty, \infty)$. Suppose $u_n(z)$ is a decreasing sequence of subharmonic functions on $D$ such that $u_n(z) \to u(z)$ for all $z \in D$.

Show that $u(z)$ is subharmonic.

Comment: Use the integral definition (the mean value criteria) for subharmonic functions.  It follows fairly easily from this.  Let me know if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 4):

Take any $z \in D$ and $r$ small enough so that $D(z,r) \subset \Omega$. Since

$$
u_n(z) \le \int_{\partial D(z,\epsilon)} u_n(\zeta)\,d\sigma(\zeta)
$$
(normalized arc length measure) for every $\epsilon < r$, monotone convergence shows that
$$
u(z) \le \int_{\partial D(z,\epsilon)} u(\zeta)\,d\sigma(\zeta).
$$

By the sub-mean value characterization of subharmonic functions, $u$ is also subharmonic. (Note that you can replace monotone convergence with locally uniform convergence if you like. Pointwise convergence is not enough, though.)